# Capture link a user clicks on a page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am playing around with making an extension. If a user has the extension installed, I would like to capture the link they clicked on a web page. Not quite sure how to do this, but it seems simple. I might add, I would like this to happen as long as the plugin is installed and enabled, but DON'T want the user to have to do anything in the toolbar to 'activate' it.

Not sure how to start. And I figure I have one too many JS files, but just trying to get one of them to log to the console. Neither do. My end goal is I would like to redirect them to an intranet page if they go to certain places.

**background.js**

```
var redirectedSites = ["https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<SOMEPROFILEID>"];
// when the browser tries to get to a page, check it against a list
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        console.log('is this even getting hit?');
        for(var i=0; i < redirectedSites.length; ++i) {
            // if the attempt is to a listed site, redirect the request
            if( details.url == redirectedSites[i] )
               return {redirectUrl: "http://intranet/landing?from=" + details.url };
         }
    },
    {urls: ["*://www.facebook.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Capture Click",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Simple tool that logs clicked links.",
 "permissions": [
"tabs",
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking",
    "https://*.facebook.com/*"
 ],
"background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: You have two message listeners but no message senders? You should include a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) that runs your jQuery code on every page and emits a message.

Comment: OK I will read that page real quick. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Worked great on my localhost, but then I tried it on Facebook, and it hit the console.log 1 out of 10 times doing the same task over and over. Weird.

Comment: I think I need to grab specific tags in the HTML parent, to make sure it's capturing all clicks. It gets about 1/2 of them. But some it's not capturing at all...

Comment: Maybe because the links are being created after your script runs?

Comment: Well I can see the link URL when I hover over them. Interesting point though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given some advice in the comments, but the best way to solve your actual larger problem is with a [webRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html) handler:

```
var redirectedSites = ["http://www.google.com/foobar", ...];
// when the browser tries to get to a page, check it against a list
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        for(var i=0; i < redirectedSites.length; ++i) {
            // if the attempt is to a listed site, redirect the request
            if( details.url == redirectedSites[i] )
                return {redirectUrl: "http://intranet/landing?from=" + details.url };
        }
    },
    {urls: ["*://www.google.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

This is a really simple example, but I hope you get the idea.  Here, `details.url` is the page the user is trying to get to, and the returned object has a `redirectUrl` property that redirects the attempt to visit the page.  My example checks `details.url` against a list of target sites; you could use a regex or something else that's more robust.

Note that this will affect not only clicked links and typed-in URLs, but also resources (scrips, images) and Ajax requests.

Comment: Ahh..This looks promising. I am going to change my background.js to this and report back. Right now I am getting this error, but we'll see after tinkering `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined
(anonymous function)`

Comment: Oops, looks like I can't place this in a content script. Lemme look around more to find out where I put it. Maybe I don't need a content script now...

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot to mention that.  It goes in your background page; you don't need a content script.

Comment: OK I got it to work, sort of. It tries to redirect to another URL, and I got this message: `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.` I was testing by redirecting from one FB page to another.

Comment: I am guessing I need to handle a signed request properly somehow? That may require another question?

Comment: Yeah, `X-Frame-Options` is a HTTP header sent by the server that says "don't display this page in an iframe" (or, "only display this in an iframe on certain trusted domains").  I don't know how Facebook applications use iframes; it's certainly a separate question.